# Sharepoint 2013 - Sql server dominating memory usage on a single machine setup

Tags: sql-server, memory-leak

I'm evaluating sharepoint 2013 on a 16GB ram box where I have the sql server and sharepoint on the same box.

I ran a script the dump a huge number of sites, sub-sites and document libraries into the thing to see how it behaves.

After running that script, SQL Server was using 13GB of ram causing lots of swap. And now on cold start sql server uses 9GB ram.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

Looks like I'm supposed to have 24GB ram but I right now only have access to a 16GB box. Is this normal or do you expect there is an issue here? Will I get away with 16GB for the remainder of this POC/trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normal, as SQL server to consume the all available ram. But we can limit the ram usage to sql server.

I.e. You have 16 gb ram and did not set the limit then sql server eat all the ram, slow down the server but one good thing, sql server good in sharing even eat all but if someone need it, it shares with that program .

With 16 gb, I would cap sql with6 or 8 gb.

Read this http://m.sharepointpromag.com/sql-server-2012/fine-tune-your-sql-server-2012-configuration-sharepoint-2013

Comment: ah excellent. i didn't even know you could do that